# can't find validatorengine namespace with nhibernate,

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-validator

I have NHibernate working opening sessions etc. I just want to initialise a new Validator engine (have put validator DLLS in my project from NHibernate validator 1.31GA) and my DLLS for NHibernate are from 3.2GA.

Have I done something wrong here, I find it so weird, it can find the NHibernate namespace obviously but not nhibernate.validator

I can't use the nhibernate vlaidator nhibernate.dll because i need to use the SQL2008 dialect which needs the 3.2 GA

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate.Validator [is not compatible with NHibernate 3.2GA](http://groups.google.com/group/nhcdevs/msg/c2ee6fa1dc52b26c). You need to take the source code and make following changes

- replaced ProxyFactoryFactoryNotConfiguredException with Exception in NHibernateHelper.cs

After that you can compile your own version which works with NHibernate 3.2. I did it and I haven't had any problems so far.

Comment: Thanks for your post! Managed to get it working, I was retarded, didn't realise i had to add a reference to the DLL in my bin folder thought it did it automatically lol L.